# SQL Server bool expression like variable

Tags: sql-server

There are many identical lines for filter in my Procedure.
Can I convert it to variable?

```
select 1 from ACCOUNTS  where
  ((KO_SRC is null and @ko is null or KO_SRC is not null and @ko is not null and KO_SRC = @ko) or 
    ((@ko is null and @insKo is null or @ko is not null and @insKo is not null and @ko = @insKo) and KO_SRC is null))   
 and ...
```

I would like get

```
SET @filter = ((KO_SRC is null and @ko is null or KO_SRC is not null and @ko is not null and KO_SRC = @ko) or 
    ((@ko is null and @insKo is null or @ko is not null and @insKo is not null and @ko = @insKo) and KO_SRC is null))

select 1 from ACCOUNTS  where @filter and ...
```

Comment: I think you are missing some parentheses in your code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but it’s easier for me to read

Comment: This looks like the beginnings of a catch-all query, or "kitchen sink", query.  If so, you would likely be far better off creating a **properly parametrised** dynamic statement to handle this, as the data engine is going to end up either not being able to compile a good plan for your query, or caching one that will only work for one of the many scenarios you cater for.

Comment: `X is not null and Y is not null and X = Y` Can be simplified to `X = Y` because `NULL` will not equal anything, not even another null.

Comment: @ZoharPeled In OP's example two nulls should return true.

Comment: @Larnu It part of big query. I have to replace ko_src = '@ko to ko_src is not null and '@ko is not null ....It will be used with partial tables

Comment: @Neophear Yes, I'm well aware of that. in fact, the reason your answer works is because my comment is correct, and you can dismiss the `KO_SRC is not null and @ko is not null` part from the `where` clause.

Comment: Then you should probably be posting the full query, @Neophear . In the mean time, have a read of [Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and [An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).

Comment: @ZoharPeled what happens if X  - null and Y - not null? X = Y will be unknown. what result will I get? I'm afraid to get a problem

Comment: The result of any test using comparison operators that involves a `null` operand will be UNKNOWN, which is equivalent to false in the context of a `where` clause: `x = null` is the same as `x != null` - both are false. [See documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a boolean datatype in SQL available on the sql server. You'll need to store the result of your operation in an integer or in a bit and then compare that value to 0 or 1 like this:

```
declare @filter bit;
set @filter = case when ((KO_SRC is ... )) then 1 else 0 end;

select 1 from accounts where @filter = 1 and ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that, as Larnu points out in the comments, this is not SARGable and thus will have bad performance. You might want to rethink your database schema to avoid nulls if possible.

You can use [isnull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like this:

```
select 1 from ACCOUNTS
where (KO_SRC = @ko or isnull(KO_SRC, @ko) is null) or ...other cases
```

Edit: I just realized that OP want a `@filter`-parameter, so this answer doesn't 100% answer the question. But it can increase readability nonetheless.

Another possibility is to create a separate function that can take the proper inputs and then return a bit representing true/false.

Comment: `ISNULL` in the `WHERE` like that is going to ruin any performance this query might have had left, as it isn't SARGable.

Comment: @Larnu I was not aware of that. Thank you for pointing that out. I'm guessing OP should rethink the database schema.